# Importing Numpy in embedded Python c++ application

Tags: c++, python-3.x, python-embedding

I would like to have a script invoke numpy from a c++ embedded python runtime by setting the runtime path to know about the numpy module located within site-packages.

However I get the error:

> cannot import name 'multiarray'

from \Lib\site-packages\numpy\core__init_.py on the line

```
from . import multiarrray
```

I have tried to set the os.path to be xxx\numpy\core but it still cannot seem to find the multiarray.pyd file during the import statement

I have read through similar questions posed but none of the answers seem relevant to my case.

I am using Python 3.4.4 (32 bit) and have installed Numpy 1.11.1 using the wheel
numpy-1.11.1-cp34-none-win32.whl

> python -m pip install numpy-1.11.1-cp34-none-win32.whl

Completed without any errors.

Seems like the failure message maybe [more general](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.lang.python/hUHCwhMCLrQ) than just an incomplete PYTHONPATH?

Also think it might be broader than Numpy in that **ANY** .pyd based package that is imported from the embedded environment will have this problem?

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like the answer was to install python 3.4.1 to match the python34.dll version of 3.4.1.

Answer (score 1):

Did you ensure all your NumPy includes: \numpy\core\include\numpy\ were present during the build?  That's the only time I get those types of errors was if the build couldn't find all the NumPy includes...  although during embedding I found that the `numpy` entire directory (already built on your build machine) has to be inside a directory under `Py_SetPath(python35.lib;importlibs);` assuming importlibs is a directory with NumPy inside and anything else you want to bundle.

Comment: Thanks. Yes I did. We have managed to get it working on another system..only difference being using python 3.4.1 instead of 3.4.4 (python34.dll was for python 3.4.1)